# What test to use for multiple dichotomous independent variables and a continuous dependent outcome

Tags: multivariate-analysis

Given the following

- multiple independent dichotomous variables (gender, over 18, etc.)
- single dependent outcome (month salary for instance)

What is the best way to determine the relative effect of each independent variable on the outcome

Comment: Why not just linear regression?